# Explain me that strings are immutable

Tags: java, string, immutability

I read a lot that string objects are immutable and only string buffers are mutable. But When I tried this program. I am confused. So whats going on here in this program.

```
class Stringss {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="hello";
        String ss=new String("xyz");
        System.out.println(ss);
        System.out.println(s);

        s="do";
        ss=new String("hello");
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
xyz
hello
do
hello
```

Comment: All 4 are different objects. What are you confused at?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, `s` is not a String object. It's a *reference* to a String object. Your code makes it reference several different String objects. But the String object itself doesn't change.

A String would not be immutable if you could do, for example

```
s.setCharacterAt(3, 'Z');
```

or

```
s.setValue("foo")
```

But doing

```
s = "a string";
s = "another string";
```

Doesn't change what the `"a string"` object contains. It just makes s point to another String.

To make an analogy, a VHS is mutable. You can replace what is on the band. A DVD is immutable: you can't change what's being written on the disk. But that doesn't prevent the DVD player to play several different DVDs. Putting another DVD inside the DVD player doesn't change what the DVDs contain.

Comment: This was explained very well. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

It means that whenever you need to edit a String, it creates a brand new String object instead of amending the original.

Comment: So how to prove that string objects are immutable. So as your point of view s="hello" and s="do" are different objects right?

Comment: When you do ` = "hello"` in Java, behind the scenes, Java is doing `s = new String("hello")`. So although s is a single object, it holds a reference to another object whenever you reassign it.

Comment: @BlackBox: no, it doesn't do that behind the scenes.

Comment: so what it does do? How the S holds the reference of another object and how I can get the older object?

Comment: Maybe bad wording, but semantically, it creates a new reference?

Comment: "hello" is already a String object. Java doesn't create a new copy of "hello" each time you assign "hello" to a variable. All the variables referencing "hello" point to the same String instance, held in a pool of String literals. That is possible precisely because String is immutable: there is no risk of a piece of code modifying the string referenced by dozens of unrelated variables.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, never knew that.

Comment: @user2824612: if you want to keep a reference to the "old" string then assign it to another variable: `String s = "hello"; String backup = s; s = "goodbye";`

Comment: @JBNizet so that means when I create a String h="World" string object it is in string pool. So whenever i create like String kk="World". This kk doesnot create a new World string object. It points to the "World" which is already present in string pool. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Only String *literals* (and Strings on which intern() has been called) are in the pool. So dynamically created or read strings (from a file, the console or whatever) are not pooled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused by the difference between the reference to the String object and the String object itself.

When you say

```
String myString = "Hello";
```

the runtime creates an object in memory "Hello." You can't directly mess with the way this object is stored because Java manages memory. But you still need to be able to make use of that object, so the reference *myString* lets you do that in an indirect way.

When you make calls on *myString* with the . operator like these:

```
myString.charAt(0)
myString.length
```

You are using your reference to get some information about that string, but you never touch the string itself.

Now it gets a little tricky. If you do this next:

```
myString = "Later";
```

The runtime creates a new object in memory "Later," and *myString* points to that now instead. "Hello" is still sitting in memory, but you have no way to get information from it anymore. Eventually, Java will figure that out and clean it up so you get that memory back for other things. This shows the *reference* can point to anything, and those things can change all the time.

Now let's say I want to change *the string itself* like this:

```
myString = myString + ", dude.";
```

It looks like you are modifying *myString* to add more stuff to it, but you actually aren't. You have the original object in memory ("Later"), and the runtime creates a second object in memory (", dude."). Then the runtime creates a *third* object that represents the combination of the two: "Later, dude."

If Strings were mutable (like StringBuffer and StringBuilder), you could have one object and just keep changing it. But they are not, so every time you think you're just modifying it, you are creating new ones. This can lead to a lot of wasted memory and then a decline in performance when the runtime tries to get it all back.

So it is about the difference between reference and object.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable means you can not modify the String object

the above three ways are same, String is not a primitive data type, its a class

Comment: can you explain me with my program

Comment: the above three ways are same, 
String is not a primitive data type, its in class

Answer (score -3):

One way to understand it may be by doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="hello";
    tryToMutateString(s);
    System.out.println(s); //Will just print "hello" since our s still refers to that
}

public static void tryToMutateString(String given) {
    given += "mutated"; //Creates a new String, the string that given pointed to earlier won't change
}
```

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with immutability. You could do the exact same thing with a StringBuilder, which is mutable. It has to do with arguments being passed by value.

Comment: You couldn't really have done with a StringBuilder though... afaik no class except for the primitive wrappers and String overload operators